# One regex for multiple strings

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have 4 different types of inputs:

- COUNT OF apples >= 18 AS oranges
- COUNT OF apples >= 18
- apples >= 18 AS oranges
- apples

I need to extract groups as

```
{group1} OF {group2} AS {group 3}
 where,
 group1 = 'COUNT'
 group2 = 'apples >= 18'
 group3 = 'apples'
```

For the first input, I can use the following regex

```
`/(.*) OF (.*) AS (.*)/g`.
```

Do I have to use separate regex for all these or will a single regex handle all these inputs?

Comment: No, you can make things optional.

Comment: javascript or python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the parts with the `OF` and `AS` optional, like:

```
 /^(?:(.*?) OF )?(.*?)(?:AS (.*))?$/
```

As you can see on [**regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/7Pxxek/1), we thus capture three groups: the part before the `OF`, the middle part, and the part ofter the `AS`.

The regex101 engine, also shows the captures:

> ```
> Match 1
> Full match    0-32    `COUNT OF apples >= 18 AS oranges`
> Group 1.  n/a `COUNT`
> Group 2.  n/a `apples >= 18 `
> Group 3.  n/a `oranges`
> Match 2
> Full match    33-54   `COUNT OF apples >= 18`
> Group 1.  n/a `COUNT`
> Group 2.  n/a `apples >= 18`
> Match 3
> Full match    55-78   `apples >= 18 AS oranges`
> Group 2.  n/a `apples >= 18 `
> Group 3.  n/a `oranges`
> Match 4
> Full match    79-85   `apples`
> Group 2.  n/a `apples`
> ```

We thus use the `(..)?` part to make certain elements optional, and `.*?` to make non-greedy captures.

Mind however that if the expression contains multiple `OF`s, or `AS`'s, then the parser will take the first `OF` as the separator, and the first `AS` as separator. So `COUNT OF apples >= 18 OF lemon < 12 AS bar AS qux` will be seprated in `[COUNT] OF [apples >= 18 OF lemon < 12] AS [bar AS qux]`.

Comment: Thank you, this is great!
Didn't know about the non-capturing group "(?:)" syntax. 
Much appreciated.